# Castle on my wallpaper - where is it?

Tags: identify-this, architecture, mountains

My operating system (Elementary OS Luna) comes with  a set of wallpapers - one of which is some kind of castle or cathedral built in mountains. Where is it?

[image: castle wallpaper]

Comment: Use google image search.

Answer (score 3):

The background is called 'Temple' by Jason Absolom.  It was one of the [announced wallpapers](http://elementaryos.org/journal/luna-wallpapers-officially-revealed) chosen in a competition for the selection of them.

I believe it is a composite image and not a real place, which is why I'm putting this as an answer, but if I'm proven wrong I'm happy to remove it.

Comment: Looking at the [other submissions](http://labs.elementaryos.org/experiment-2/results/) by the same artist, it's quite obvious that he does submit a lot of composite images, so this seems to be a reasonable assumption.

Comment: You spoiled my fu, @Mark. I was just about to Answer, "Gondolin".

Answer (score 1):

It's quite certainly a composite. Building on @MarkMayo's answer I figured tin eye might help and it did. Sadly the original image is a stock image and seems hard to find the origin. From some of the places the picture has been used [here](http://www.zillertal-hotel.de/zillertal/urlaub/) it seems likely it is in the Tiroli alps.